# I need a Spring AOP pointcut explanation

Tags: spring, aop, pointcut

I have seen two variations of pointcut patterns:

This

```
execution(* some.package.*.*(..))
```

and this

```
execution(* some.package.* *(..))
```

What is the meaning of the dot (or of it absence) between the last two *'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [appendix](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) defines grammar of the pointcut expression langauge. For the execution expression the rule is the following:

```
execution(MethodPattern)
```

where

```
MethodPattern = 
  [ModifiersPattern] TypePattern 
        [TypePattern . ] IdPattern (TypePattern | ".." , ... ) 
        [ throws ThrowsPattern ]
```

That means that if you have 3 expressions (separated by space) before "(", then the first is modifier, second is class and third is method name. But if you have 2 expressions before "(", then first will be class and second will be method name.

Comment: Ok, it's getting a little clearer now. But in the production rule I have two places to put a TypePattern, what is the difference between using one or the other? Does it make sense to use both?

Comment: I think there is no difference, but it is a bit confusing to use both type patterns at once. But probably in some situations it may be useful to refer to inner types.

Comment: I actually do think there is a difference, it behaved very differently in a use case I had, but I don't understand the principle behind the difference

Comment: Now I'm starting to understand it myself :). First TypePattern is actually a return type of the method, second TypePattern is location class of the method.